# Populate multiple labels and/or textbox from XML document when combobox selected change C#

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

The code below works with listview selected index change but now I am trying to do the same thing with a combobox selected index change to which it does not work the same.

```
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\loco\Desktop\Save\C# Programming\Trash\addressTest1" + "\\Address Book - Jonsey"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\loco\Desktop\Save\C# Programming\Trash\addressTest1" + "\\Address Book - Jonsey");
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\loco\Desktop\Save\C# Programming\Trash\addressTest1" + "\\Address Book - Jonsey\\settings.xml"))
        {

            XmlTextWriter xmDoc = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\loco\Desktop\Save\C# Programming\Trash\addressTest1" + "\\Address Book - Jonsey\\settings.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
          xmDoc.WriteStartElement("People");
          xmDoc.WriteEndElement();
          xmDoc.Close();  
        }


        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\loco\Desktop\Save\C# Programming\Trash\addressTest1" + "\\Address Book - Jonsey\\settings.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("People/People"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
            p.Email = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText;
            p.StreetAddress = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Address").InnerText;
            p.AdditionalNotes = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Notes").InnerText;
            p.Birthday = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("Birthday").InnerText));
            people.Add(p);
            listView1.Items.Add(p.Name);




        }
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            return;
        textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
        textBox2.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
        textBox3.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].StreetAddress;
        textBox4.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].AdditionalNotes;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Birthday;



    }
```

This is the combobox example that I have to which when a selected index is selected from the combobox it only reads the first set of values and not the second or third and so on and so forth.  So basically what I need is when each index is selected change each variable to each label or textbox.

```
      private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
        textBox2.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;

    }
```

I tried to using if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;  but it does work with combobox.  Tried to find a variation of this but it seems that I missing something.

This is the XML document example.

```
        <People>
          <People>
            <Name>luke barb</Name>
            <Email>luke@barb.com</Email>
            <Address>;lkdjf;l</Address>
            <Notes>fdj;ljsf;lkd;sfksadkjf</Notes>
            <Birthday>130487387130000000</Birthday>
          </People>
          <People>
            <Name>jake heckle</Name>
            <Email>df;lksjfl</Email>
            <Address>;ladjf;lkdsj</Address>
            <Notes>df;lka;lfkj;lasjfd;lkjds</Notes>
            <Birthday>116930363500000000</Birthday>
          </People>
          <People>
            <Name>bob hook</Name>
            <Email>kjad;lfkj</Email>
            <Address>kdjf;lkjf;la</Address>
            <Notes>j;dlkjskfjskjf;lsf</Notes>
            <Birthday>111250427730000000</Birthday>
          </People>
        </People>
```

Comment: What values you are populating in combobox? Why listview.SelectedItems is being used in combobox_selectedIndexChanged? What exact output do you want? And what unexpected output you are getting?

Comment: I need for each People in People to populate each name, email, address, notes and birthday to a separate label like label1.text, label2.text so on an so forth when when a combobox index is selected. What I am getting is that when an index is selected from the combobox only the first people in people and nothing else.  For example if i selected the second index  Jake Heckle from the combobox it still only show the first one luke barb.